# WF4 Activity does not have Id

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I was wondering, how to get an Id for a simple activity. For example:

```
        Sequence s = new Sequence();
        string id = s.Id;
```

The id is always null and as it has a private Setter I cannot set this value.
Under which circumstances will this value be filled with an Id and by whom?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is set when you use the WorkflowDesigner or at runtime. But even then it can be tricky to work with because it can take on a different form in the WorkflowDesigner depending on how you load the workflow.

Comment: Tahnks. Is there a possibility to intercept and grab the activity id as soon as it is created by the WorkflowDesigner?

Answer (score 0):

You may use WorkflowInspectionServices to list activities from the root activity. When using WorkflowInspectionServices, the ids are set.

With a recursive function like this one :

```
void WriteActivities(Activity p_activity, int p_offset)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{2}Activity : {0}, {3} ({1})", p_activity.Id, p_activity.GetType().Name, new String('-', p_offset), p_activity.DisplayName);
    IEnumerable<Activity> l_activities = WorkflowInspectionServices.GetActivities(p_activity);

    foreach (Activity l_childActivity in l_activities)
    {
        WriteActivities(l_childActivity, p_offset + 1);
    }
}
```